# Laravel best way to handle measurement formatting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am dealing with a lot of measurements currently and I know that this could cause a lot of issues in the long run if done manually.

For example:
I am storing weight (`$weight = 50.55`) as an integer in the database (`5055`)

However, when I want to present ideally I would want

- A presenter format ("50.55 LBS")
- Real weight format ("50.55")
- Multiplied by 100 format (int 5055)

If I use accesssors I would add 3 methods per field, considering I would need to do this for weight, height, width, length that seems a little verbose (12 methods)

What would be a reusable (Laravel) way to deal with this?

Also would welcome better naming suggestions

Comment: Create a helper function taking output type, multiplier or whatever you need and call it while displaying guessing that won't be causing any performance issues because doing it via Mutatators or via helper function, doing it via helper function will be single function to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Custom Cast https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

like this

```
class MeasureCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $value / 100;
    }

    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $value * 100;
    }

    public static function print($value): string
    {
        return $value . ' LBS';
    }
}
```

in model

```
    protected $casts = [
        'weight' => MeasureCast::class,
    ];
```

it help save/read in properly format.

when you want print - write `MeasureCast::print($invoice->amount_due)`

Comment: Now that looks like the "laravel" way, I knew I should ve been paying more attention to this feature. I will implement this tomorrow and give better feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea is to cast attribute to `WeightAttribute` class instance and place all additional methods there. After that you can use it: `$model->weight->formatted()` and etc